# Schedule/Edit Maintenance Tasks for SQL Express (No Maintenance Plan Wizard)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-agent, maintenance-plan

I am using SQL Server 11.0.6251 Express (SQL Server 2012 Express). I have some software that logs data to the database continuously. However, there are some maintenance tasks that are performed on the database every so often. Whenever this happens, there are some data points that don't get logged.

I want to reschedule and configure these maintenance tasks so that I can recreate the problem and troubleshoot the software so that I don't lose any more data points.

I am aware that an easy way to do this is to just upgrade SQL Server so that I have the maintenance plan wizard and SQL Server agent. I just want to see if any of you SQL gurus out there know a way around this problem!

I've also looked into how scripts and using the Windows Task Scheduler can help create maintenance plans, but I'm not sure how to use that to edit existing maintenance tasks.

Is there any way to edit and re-schedule current Maintenance Tasks for SQL Server Express?

Comment: Powershell and use SMO?

Comment: I think I would pay money to have Windows task scheduler removed from my windows machines.  In any case, there are multiple schedulers out there . . . cron comes to mind if you have a Unix frame of mind -- but Stack Overflow is not a place to recommend software.

Comment: Something does not match here. The Express database engine does not support the agent, which is the only built-in method of "scheduling" tasks. So if you have tasks that are executing on some schedule, all of that definition and timing is done externally to your instance (though it might be storing information in a database within your express instance). Therefore, you should look to whatever app has this functionality to "adjust" anything.

Comment: Thanks @SMor ... I'm new the SQL world. The software I am using was handed to me to work on. So it's safe to assume that maintenance tasks are not being run on my database by the express database engine? In that case, I will do further digging to try to find what is causing these interruptions.

Comment: @dfundako Looks useful, I'll look into this

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the suggestion, never heard of cron but will definitely look into this